# read text file into matrix - python

Tags: python, matrix

I have a text file which contains m rows like the following:

> 0.4698537878,0.1361006627,0.2400000000,0.7209302326,0.0054816275,0.0116666667,1
>   0.5146649986,0.0449680289,0.4696969697,0.5596330275,0.0017155500,0.0033333333,0
>   0.4830107706,0.0684999306,0.3437500000,0.5600000000,0.0056351257,0.0116666667,0
>   0.4458490073,0.1175445834,0.2307692308,0.6212121212,0.0089169801,0.0200000000,0

I tried to read the file and copy it into a matrix like in the following code:

```
import string

file = open("datasets/train.txt",encoding='utf8')

for line in file.readlines():
    tmp = line.strip()
    tmp = tmp.split(",")
    idx = np.vstack(tmp)
    idy = np.hstack(tmp[12])

matrix = idx
```

I want to read the file as its into the matrix, in my sample data the matrix size should be: (4,6)
and idy: (4,1) # the last line, the labels

but it stacked the last line of the file vertically !?
like that:

> 0.4458490073,
>
> 0.1175445834,
>
> 0.2307692308,
>
> 0.6212121212,
>
> 0.0089169801,
>
> 0.0200000000,
>
> 0

any help?

Comment: How is `np` defined?

Comment: Numpy library ..

Comment: Does your actual file have new lines in it?

Comment: The problem with your original code is that `idx = np.vstack(tmp)` doesn't concatenate 'tmp' vertically into an existing array `idx`; it just turns `tmp` into a vertical array, then replaces `idx` with that. You could fix your code by using `idx = []` before the loop, then `idx.append(tmp)` inside the loop, then `matrix = np.array(idx)` after the loop completes. Then use @jp_data_analysis's technique to split the matrix into id and data parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `numpy`, this functionality is already available:

```
arr = np.genfromtxt('file.csv', delimiter=',')
```

You can then separate headers as follows:

```
data = arr[:, :-1]
header = arr[:, -1:]
```

Comment: thanx, but how can i get the last line "labels" independently ?

Answer (score 1):

This should get you the right shape (4,6) for the idx variable and (4,1) for the labels

```
alllines = open('train.txt', 'r').readlines()
# shape (4,6)
idx = np.matrix([line.replace('\n', '').split(',')[0:6] for line in alllines])
# reshape to (4,1) for labels
idy = np.matrix([line.replace('\n', '').split(',')[6] for line in alllines]).reshape(-1, 1)
```

Comment: are there any other way with determining the lengths of the matrix "dynamic" ?

Comment: @MIBMinion I just changed the solution for the idy variable so you don't have to know anything ahead of time. But if your data is wider, and you don't know how wide it is, I would use the other solution genfromtxt and pull out the labels separately.